# use a foreign key in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to use the primary key "id" on another child node. is there any way I can do that? I'm using android studio.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Realtime Database doesn't have a concept of "primary key" or "foreign key".  There are just nodes with unique IDs, and children with values.  There is no schema like SQL.  If you want to reference a different node, you are certainly able to do so by storing the path or unique ID, or whatever you want.  But it's up to you to keep all that data correctly.  The database will not stop you from writing values that don't actually correspond to other nodes.